# Template specialization for derived classes with a common base

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I want to make template specializations for classes with unknown name, I only know their base, and i want all derived classes to fall onto the specialized template functions.

The following code is a working one for Case 1-4. I couldn't make Case 5 to work.
Also this is mostly runtime checking with the is_base_of, a much more effective one would be a compile time solution, but i failed at that. :(

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass {};
struct Rnd : public MyClass {};
void* JustAVoidPointer=new int;
void* AnOtherPointer = new int;

struct A
{
    template <typename T> operator T() const {
        if (std::is_base_of<MyClass, T>::value == true)
        {
            JustAVoidPointer = (MyClass*)(new T);
            std::cout << "Case 3"; return *((T*)(JustAVoidPointer)); 
        }
        std::cout << "Case 1"; return *((T*)AnOtherPointer); 
    }
    //template <typename T> operator T&()  {
    //  std::cout << "Case 5"; return *(this->operator T* ());
    //}
    template <typename T> operator T*() const {
        if (std::is_base_of<MyClass, T>::value == true)
        {
            JustAVoidPointer = (MyClass*) new T;
            std::cout << "Case 4"; return (T*)(JustAVoidPointer); 
        }
        std::cout << "Case 2"; return *((T**)AnOtherPointer); 
    }
}a;

void main()
{
    auto CantUseTheStructsName = [&]() {
        struct Rnd : public MyClass {};
        int z = a; //Case 1
        int* w = a; //Case 2
        Rnd x = a; //Case 3
        Rnd* y = a; //Case 4
        //Rnd& z=a; //Case 5
        char* xx=0; std::cin >> xx;
    }; CantUseTheStructsName();
}
```

I would appreciate any help or advice what you could give me, Thank you!:)

Comment: Your code does not compile as-is. Is case 5 supposed to create an instance like the other cases?

Comment: Typeinfo have to be included to use is_base_of, I edited to a fully working version.
Yeah with case 5 I also want to create an instance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It makes very little sense to pass out `new`ed objects from a class. Even less sense to pass them out through conversion overloads.

Comment: To address the case 5, a conversion will return a value. This will in itself always be a temporary that you can assign to a variable. You can not bind a reference to a temporary, so that is just impossible. It would be the equivalent of doing `int& b = 2;`

Comment: @super A conversion doesn't necessarily have to return a value, your can have a conversion operator that returns a reference. That is how `std::reference_wrapper` is implemented.

Comment: Please describe what you're really trying to do, this definitely seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Right now not even cases 1 and 2 are working. Unless `T = int` or `T` inherits from `MyClass`, you're invoking undefined behaviour as you're dereferencing a pointer to a `T` that actually points to an `int` instead of a `T` (or it points to a subclass of `MyClass` if cases 3/4 resp. were already used before, but that still can't be the same type as `T`). Additionally you're leaking memory all over the place.

Comment: The pointers are not always int, I'm checking the types at runtime, also i'm deleting the allocated vars on an other part of the program.
My problem is that I can't differentiate between a reference conversion operator and a non reference one. 
If i only have  "template <typename T> operator T()  {}", then a reference conversion will say that there is no accaptable conversion, if I have both:
template <typename T> operator T()  {}
template <typename T> operator T&()  {}
Then all traffic will go to the second template specialization, and the first one will never be used.

Comment: I made an error with my title by assuming that the problem lies with is_base_of<> and that's why i cant make the reference conversion. However i don't think that i made an XY problem, i really need this exact solution. I'm making a homemade function wrapper where the calling order of arguments with different types doesn't matter, and there is a class with other rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that it's impossible to differentiate between a reference operator template and a non reference one, the reference one always takes precedence if we provide both. 
A workaround, and a compile time solution:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass {};
struct Rnd : public MyClass {};
void* JustAVoidPointer=0;
void* AnOtherPointer = new int;

struct A
{
    template <typename T, typename F = T*> operator T&() const {
        return *((T*)CheckType(F{}, std::is_pointer<T>{}, std::is_base_of<MyClass, std::remove_pointer<T>::type>{}));
    }

    template <typename T> T* CheckType(T*, std::false_type, std::false_type) const {
        std::cout << "  Case 1";
        return ((T*)AnOtherPointer);
    }
    template <typename T> T* CheckType(T*, std::true_type, std::false_type) const {
        std::cout << "  Case 2";
        return ((T*)AnOtherPointer);
    }
    template <typename T> T* CheckType(T*, std::false_type, std::true_type) const {
        std::cout << "  Case 3";
        JustAVoidPointer = (MyClass*)(new T);
        return ((T*)JustAVoidPointer);
    }
    template <typename T> T* CheckType(T*, std::true_type, std::true_type) const {
        std::cout << "  Case 4";
        JustAVoidPointer = (MyClass*)(new std::remove_pointer<T>::type);
        return ((T*)(&JustAVoidPointer));
    }
}a;


void main()
{
    auto CantUseTheStructsName = [&]() {
        struct Rnd : public MyClass {};
        int x = a; //Case 1
        int& y = a; //Case 1
        int* z = a; //Case 2
        Rnd j = a; //Case 3
        Rnd& k = a; //Case 3
        Rnd* f = a; //Case 4
        char* xx=0; std::cin >> xx;
    }; CantUseTheStructsName();
}
```

Comment: The reference one doesn't always take precedence. In fact, if you provide both `operator T` and `operator T&` (both marked as const or both not marked as const) the compiler will reject any attempt to obtain a non-pointer through conversion as ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah sry, wanted to say that if we have T x = a; and T& y = a; then if we just provide operator for T() then the compiler will ask for the &T() version, but if we have &T() we cannot have T() with implicit conversions as you said, and with operator &T()  we lose the information whether its a reference conversion or not, so &T(){std::is_reference<T>} is always false for single references, so that's why i think that we cant differentiate between the two calls: T x = a; T& y = a; .